# Filtering search results with django-haystack / solr produces solr syntax error

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I think I may have identified a bug in haystack / solr but I'm not sure and wanted to see if I'm doing something completely wrong first. I'm using:

django 1.8
haystack 2.4.1
solr 4.10.4

When I try to filter my SearchQuerySet, SOLR complains of invalid syntax on the filter query that is genenerated from haystack. Bizarrely, stepping through the code in pdb works, but it all fails under normal circumstances. The relevant portion of code is:

```
    # this is built from a query string but essentially resolves to something like
    applicable_filters = {'job_type__in':['PE', 'TE'], 'sector__in':['12','13']}

    # Do the query.
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(self._meta.queryset.model).filter(**applicable_filters).order_by(order).load_all().auto_query(request.GET.get('q', ''))
    if not sqs:
        sqs = EmptySearchQuerySet()
```

When executing this query, SOLR throws the following:

```
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: Failed to query Solr using '(job_type:("PE" OR "TE") AND sector:("12" OR "13") AND )': [Reason: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '(job_type:("PE" OR "TE") AND sector:("12" OR "13") AND )': Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 55.
```

As you can see, it appears that haystack ( or perhaps pysolr ? ) is adding an extra AND clause to the SOLR query, which seems completely wrong. The really bizarre bit is if I step through the same function in pdb it works.

am at a loss....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Problem was that I was passing an empty string to the final auto_query() clause. I've migrated from a whoosh backend and that seems more tolerant of an empty search string than SOLR.